# What's change with detach of process on windows 11 compared with windows 10 from python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, process, windows-11

I used to start detached Robot Framework process in python (3.7 - 3.11) code similar to this:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen([robot.exe,[your_test_path]], shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)
```

the important part of this code for process detach was

```
shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True
```

but it stops working on Windows 11. The process was immediately stopped when the parent was stopped.

I had to fix it. And i make it this way after some investigation:

```
process = subprocess.Popen([robot.exe,[your_test_path]], shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True, start_new_session=True, creationflags=subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS)
```

Now it works on windows 10 and 11 too. The important parametr seems to be:

```
creationflags=subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS
```

The docu is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS)

But I still wondering what changed and what is the best way to start minimized/hidden detached process.

Because my test with notepad.exe works well for this on windows 11 too.
But in the code for the robot, it isn't work.

Also started some strange embedded Terminal Window processes. Any insight somebody?

Comment: It's unspecific. Post a [mre] including the example of the child process. Anyway it seems your child process is a windows console application, and I suspect you executed the parent Python interpreter as a console application(python.exe) in Windows 11, and as a windows application(pythonw.exe) in Windows 10. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags).

Comment: Minimal example is first line of the code. 100% reproducible when called from the script on windows 11. Everybody who used popen and detech I thnik understand this part of this code. The app is command line app as mentioned Robot Framework. The Robot Framework indeed start the python (the same binary in wich is running this code). Does it have any Influance? Could you be more specific in your answere? The process cration flags I already mentioned in the link to the docu for popen. But I don't see any specific part you are refering to.

Comment: You need to post the example of the child process. You mean it is just the Python interpreter python.exe? How did you run the parent process? Did you really read [mre]? With a [mre], everyone should be able to run the experiment and reproduce the same problem on his own environment.

Comment: Sorry, it is absolutly out of my time socpe. If boder you, just leave it. The process structure is complicated and different accoridng conditions.  I can't describe whole infrustructure. I just isolated the issue. And find the solution. Child process is robot.exe.  I don't know how exactly is started parent process. But probably you can reproduce the same way from python console (jsut copy comand and raplace by your process that is command line - robot.exe is enouch). I will edit it for you :-)

Comment: I just share with community if sombody else have the sam issue as for example [link]https://superuser.com/questions/1765858/windows-11-console-closing-early-compared-to-windows-10 . Becouse it takes me few hours to figure out change in detaching between windows 10 and 11

Comment: Now it is edited, just instal robot framework and start your test like this. Probalby the same issue is also with different long runing processes ... like start python form python. (replace robot.exe with python.exe and never ending script with while for example...)

Comment: btw. the parametrs shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True shoudl be enough for detaching on windows 10 (according stackoverflow and many comments a my long term usage...). But are not enough on windows 11. This is the main point. That you absolutly missed, by your comments.

Comment: How did you run the parent process? Did you run it on Windows Terminal in Windows 11? If it is, try on the ```cmd.exe```.

Comment: I just thinking if it is possible diffrent way. The chain of child and parents is explorer.exe -> cmd.exe -> robot.exe -> python.exe -> cmd.exe -> robot.exe -> python.exe  . The last 3 processes with python.exe are detaching.... . In the case the first robot was started by windows scheduler via comand line.

Comment: I have the opposite sort of problem but maybe related to the same Win11 changes, child process stops when parent stops, but I do NOT use DETACHED_PROCESS as I want the child to continue using the same console that the parent creates. [link to my question](https://superuser.com/questions/1765858/windows-11-console-closing-early-compared-to-windows-10/1770222#1770222)

Answer (score 0):

So there is a bug in versions of Windows terminal less than version 17 (which is available in Preview, not sure when the general release is, but soon, I suppose).  It was the source of my similar problem.